# Angular-UI Keep Accordion Open During Interval Update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an accordion group that I use `ng-repeat` to produce dynamic groups, works fine. I also have `$interval` to update the list every 60 secs. When this happens all the groups close. How can I keep the last group open that that user clicked on?

```
<uib-accordion>
  <uib-accordion-group class="test" ng-repeat="item in ItemsPW">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      Header Stuff
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    <div>
      Body Contents Here
    </div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
 </uib-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is-open="variable"` that let you to assign a variable in order to know and control the state of each accordion-group.

```
<uib-accordion>
  <uib-accordion-group class="test" ng-repeat="item in ItemsPW" is-open="accordionsOpen[$index]">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      Header Stuff
    </uib-accordion-heading>
    <div>
      Body Contents Here
    </div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
 </uib-accordion>
```

So all you have to do is before reload data, save the opened accordion, reload data and open it again.

You cannot keep opened due to angular scope inheritance concept. I mean, y you remove an element of array and push another, angular have to delete the previous and insert the new.

Comment: I saw that, but I guess I am unsure of how to implement it with dynamic content. There may be one group or several groups, but the last one the user clicks needs to be open.

Comment: You have to create an array of is-open variables. use for example accordionsOpen[$index]